# Opens in mobile push are not reflected in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk, mobilepush-android

Recently we have created and integrated an android app into the Mobile push of Mobile Studio. We have implemented
the Marketing Cloud Mobile Push Android SDK in the app. Additionally, to implement analytics in our mobile app, we have set the analyticsEnabled parameter of the SDK to 'true', as suggested in the document.

After installation of the app, devices are not getting integrated automatically to our account i.e. Opt-ins not updated autmotically. We manually imported the contacts usinh APIs but then we are not getting the Opens reflected in the Mobile push page when we do open the push notifications. Opens are 0 even after opening push notifications in various devices.

Comment: Are you overriding notification handling?

Comment: Also, you say the devices are not getting registered?  Did you check the SDK's logs? (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/loginterface.html) <-- this should be done _BEFORE_ you call the SDK's initialization method.

Comment: No, we have not added this. We will add this and check and reply back here. But isn't it just for logging and troubleshooting? How will it effect the opens tracking or direct integration of device into the account?

Comment: Well, how will you know if something is going wrong without debugging or reviewing the logs?  :)  And, you did not answer: are you overriding notification handling?

Comment: As, for the registration of devices, we added the logs and nothing usual showed up or no error was found. Any new devices are not listed in the marketing cloud but when we manually add them using imports then are able to send push notifications to the devices and they are being successfully received.

Comment: We were overriding the notification handling, we removed and checked again. Still the opens are not registered in marketing cloud. After using logs along with overriding notifications handling as given in http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/trouble-shooting/multiple-push-sdks.html, we observed: 
BehaviorManager: Behavior found: BEHAVIOR_SDK_PUSH_RECEIVED
BehaviorManager: Behavior found: BEHAVIOR_SDK_NOTIFICATION_OPENED. However, error we encountered: !j: Sync route request failed with message: Not Found. 
Sdk Version: 6.4.0
Google Play Services Version: 12451000

Comment: You should open a support case.  It does not appear that you have implemented the SDK correctly -- to get devices registered automatically via the SDK requires that you add a dependency and you call init.  There is no other magic.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort @BillMote. We have opened a support case. Will look forward for help from their side.

Comment: Hopefully, they'll straighten you out before it gets all the way to me ;)